# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'InfoController' not found on type com.ui.InfoTemplate

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-1.2, ibm-was

Hi I am trying to migrating my application from WAS 6.0 to WAS 8.5 with minimal code change. My application is written in JSF 1.1 which is not supported in WAS8.5. I have written its getters and setters also. This application is working fine in WAS6.0/6.1 but while running in WAS8.5 it is showing Exceptions. What all Jars i have to add in my project so that it will work. I am getting following exceptions:

```
javax.el.ELException: Property 'InfoController' not found on type com.ui.InfoTemplate javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.ELException: Property 'InfoController' not found on type com.ui.InfoTemplate
at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.ValueExpressionToValueBinding.getValue(ValueExpressionToValueBinding.java:169)
at com.utilities.JsfUtility.getManagedBean(JsfUtility.java:107)
at com.ui.LandingPageController.getInfo(LandingPageController.java:92)

Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Property 'InfoController' not found on type com.ui.InfoTemplate
at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:127)

Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Property 'InfoController' not found on type com.ui.InfoTemplate
at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:80)

Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'InfoController' not found on type com.ui.InfoTemplate
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:232)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:209)
```

Comment: It's okay that you obfuscate package/class names in stack trace, but as long as you're still new to the stuff and thus can easily unawaringly introduce new bugs while editing them out, then you should absolutely recreate the problem in a blank sandbox project so that you can just copy code/stacktraces **unmodified** into the question. The stack trace namely represents the whole answer at its own (we just have to translate the stack trace in layman's terms). If you edit one small thing in code or stack trace the wrong way without actually testing it, then the answer may completely disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've an EL syntax error. The exception message suggests that you've something like

```
public class InfoTemplate {

    public InfoController getInfoController() {
        return infoController;
    }

}
```

And that you're attempting to access the property as `InfoController`:

```
#{infoTemplate.InfoController}
```

This is wrong. The property name, when not starting with 2 capitals or more, must start with lowercase.

```
#{infoTemplate.infoController}
```

I'm not sure how it worked in older WAS version. It should have failed the same way over there.

Comment: Hi, in my jsp page i am calling  `<f:param value="#{pInfoTemplate.memberName}" />` and in my class: 
 public class PersonalInfoTemplate {
     private String memberName = "";//getters and setters of membername

}

Comment: That param calls `getMemberName()`, not `getInfoController()`.